# Let a, b, c, and d be integers, and let n be a positive integer:

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that a ≡ b mod n and c ≡ d mod n.

(a) Prove that a + c ≡b +d mod n.

(b) Prove that a −c ≡ b − d mod n

Comment: What have you tried? What does it mean for $a$ to be congruent to $b$ modulo $n$? Try un-packaging the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your modulo equations as $$a=b+nk_1,c=d+nk_2$$ where $k_1,k_2$ are integers

Comment: Almost exactly the hint I was typing out.